# Smooth circular collisions with edges/collision boxes [C# + XNA]

Tags: xna, c#, collision-detection, xna-4.0

So, me and a friend are working on our top-down perspective 2D game, and have come to work on perfecting our collisions. In its current state our player sprite is colliding with walls, but is experiencing a "sticking" to the collided surface. This is mainly because our collisions only consist of "if colliding on X axsis, stop X movement":

```
if (boxR.Intersects(playerCircle)) {
    if (playerCircle.center.X <= boxR.X + boxR.Width || playerCircle.center.X >= boxR.X)
        stopX = true;
    if (playerCircle.center.Y <= boxR.Y + boxR.Height || playerCircle.center.Y >= boxR.Y)
        stopY = true;
}
```

What we are intending is smoothed collisions, so that if we hold down the S key (for down), and the player's collision circle hits the corner of a collision rectangle, then the sprite's brute force of moving down pushes itself to the side to continue without further collision. Example below; the solid line is the input vector, while the dotted line is the adjusted vector because of the collisions with the corner.

[image]

Is there a seemingly simple adjustment to be made? Or will we need to incorporate some sort of physics library to get around this? If so, then what would you suggest?

Comment: If you could get the intersection's point, then you could substract the vector between the intersection's point and the circle's center from the movement vector.

Comment: @Zhafur Maybe also normalize the length of that vector and then times it by the combined speed of the two objects before subtracting?

Comment: Got it (after a few painstaking days of blood sweat and tears). It's rather extremely complicated, so I won't go into the details. Thanks you two, helps me brainstorm.